# Q: Facebook SDK Main Activity

Tags: java, android

When they tell me to add default activity class name, should I write `com.example.milanovic.hellou.MainActivity` or `MainActivity` or `.MainActivity`.
`com.example.milanovic.hellou` is the name of the package I'm using.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, since you specify your package in the AndroidManifest.xml file, the MainActivity's package should be specified relatively to that. For example, if you package is `com.example.app` and your activity is `com.example.app.Activity`, then you can type it as `.Activity`(without dot is also fine), but if it is different, then full package as `totally.different.package.Activity`, if it is subpackage, try: `.subpackage.name.Activity`

Finally in your case it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.milanovic.hellou">

    ...

    <application ...>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```